# What kills the parent process?

Tags: c, unix, process, posix, kill

What ends the parent process in this code? I see don't see him exiting anywhere... 
A friend of mine says that the parent isn't ended/kiled, the code simply stops at the last exit(0). If this is the case, then what wakes the parent process from sleep? Thank you in advance

```
adghtesd
```

the results of the program:

```
    parent: I'm the parent
    child: I'm the child
    child: I'm exiting
    parent: child process (PID=1919) exited with value 123
    parent: exiting
    test
```

Comment: The parent process runs the function `il_parent`. Then the `il_parent` function returns, and goes back to the `main` function and its `switch`. The `switch` ends, and the `exit(0)` function at the end is called. This could be easily verified if you tried to debug your program, either through [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) or by stepping through the code in an actual debugger.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude but the code stops right after the child has ended his work. Notice how child has 3 seconds of sleep and parent has 10, but right after child ends, parent stops sleeping and the code ends with exit(0).

Comment: @MrMoil By the way, it is not allowed to call `exit` from signal handlers (and `printf` too).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this POSIX reference on `sleep`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sleep.html):

> If `sleep()` returns because the requested time has elapsed, the value returned shall be 0. If `sleep()` returns due to delivery of a signal, the return value shall be the "unslept" amount (the requested time minus the time actually slept) in seconds.

What happens for you is that when the parent process receives the `SIGCHLD` signal, it causes the `sleep` function to be interrupted, and the parent continues after the `sleep` call.

If you want to sleep the full amount, you need to check what `sleep` returns, and call `sleep` in a loop until it returns `0`.

Comment: Also it would be easier to implement this with `nanosleep`, `clock_nanosleep` or C11 `thrd_sleep` as they provide the remaining time.